# In mybatis-config.xml, how do different users use different usernames to login into the same datasource?

Tags: jakarta-ee, mybatis

In mybatis-config.xml, how do different users use different usernames to login into the same datasource? For example, I have "student", "teacher" and "administor" three different schema in one unique Oracle datasource. How should I configure the mybatis to let different user login to the unique datasource by different username? Does it have to configure multiple "environment" sections?

Some confuesd concepts are there in above, let me say precisely my question:
Could I configure multiple datasources with same driver and url properties but different username?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure single datasource with credentials which has access to all three users/schemas.

In your mybatis queries you need to prefix the table names with user/schema names.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
  PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
  "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
  <environments default="development">
    <environment id="development">
      <transactionManager type="JDBC"/>
      <dataSource type="POOLED">
        <property name="driver" value="${driver}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
      </dataSource>
    </environment>
  </environments>
  <mappers>
     <mapper resource="BlogMapper.xml"/>    
  </mappers>
</configuration>
```

**BlogMapper.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
  PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
  "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="org.mybatis.example.BlogMapper">

  <select id="selectBlog" resultType="Blog">
    select * from blog.blogs where id = #{id}
  </select>

  <select id="selectUser" resultType="User">
    select * from security.users where id = #{id}
  </select>

</mapper>
```

Note referencing the tables using **blog.blogs** and **security.users**.

Comment: Excuse me? What are credentials? Could you give me a segment of code in XML format?

Comment: By credentials I mean database username/password. Updated answer to include sample configurations.